# Where to close a member variable (e.g.:socket) in a java class?

Tags: java, sockets, destructor

In my case, the member variable is socket. But this question can be general for any member variable which needs some operations before the object is deleted.

I created a java class "DB" which has a socket member. I create the socket member in constructor.
The socket will keep open until this class "DB" object be GC. Since we should close the socket using "socket.close()" and Java doesn't support destructor. 
In this case, I wonder where should I put "socket.close()"? Overwrite "finalize()" as below ?

I heard finalize() is deprecated method. 
Then what will be long term solution for this kind of issue which a member variable need some operation before the object is deleted ?

Thanks.

```
@Override
protected void finalize() throws IOException 
{
    m_socket.close();
}
```

Comment: finalize is called sometime between the GC finds that the object is unreachable and before the memory is reclaimed. Isn't there a better life cycle of your object that you can depend on?

Comment: There is no Java solution for knowing when a socket, or really any resource, should be "closed" or cleaned up. Logic specific to your usage will dictate when you are finished with the socket, and at that point it should be closed. The same is true of a file or a database connection or whatever.

Comment: So it means, in this case, I should provide a close method which wrap the socket.close() and let the user to call it ?

Comment: Yes. Make the class `implement AutoCloseable` and move the problem to the caller. Leaving sockets open until GC is a poor strategy, as it may never happen.